# Arrange cards on left and right using BS4, without having parent columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 and without Javascript, how can I create an arrangement like this when the viewport is large:
    [image: Large viewport card arrangement]

And an arrangement like this when the viewport is constrained:
    [image: Small viewport card arrangement]

The only way I could get it to look like the large viewport arrangement was by doing this:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">

  <div class="col-8 column-1">

    <form class="card text-center" action="runthis" method="GET">
      <div class="card-header">Hello</div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" autofocus="" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="full_name2" placeholder="Full Name/>
        <input type=" text " class="form-control input-lg " name="full_name3 " placeholder="Name " />
        <button name="Submit " value"submit " class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div> <!-- end column-1 -->

  <div class="col-4 column-2">
    <div class="card p-3">
      <blockquote class="card-block card-blockquote">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block ">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title 2</h4>
        <p class="card-text ">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text "><small class="text-muted ">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see this code in action at ***https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKoPWx***

As you can see from this code above, it doesn't allow the ability to collapse as desired when the viewport is constrained due to the parent columns of the left and right sections.

How can I do this without having parent columns?

Comment: Post the code in the question instead of a link

Comment: @ZimSystem updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the new BS 4 utility classes to float the columns accordingly on larger screens. Then they will stack on their natural order on smaller (xs) screens.

https://www.codeply.com/go/A6F3GT1xw8

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-block">
        <div class="col-sm-4 float-sm-right">
            <div class="card p-3">
                card 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 float-sm-left">
            <form class="card text-center" action="runthis" method="GET">
               card 1
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 float-sm-left">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block ">
                    card 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```